# How to get list of available commands for Entity Framework in package manager console

Tags: entity-framework, package-manager-console

I want to know if its possible to **get a list of** available **commands** **for Entity Framework** (or other NuGet installed packages) **in package manager console**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, you just need to type

```
PM> get-help entityframework
```

in Package Manager Console to see all available Entity-Framework commands.

here is the useful link about entityframework commands in Package Manager Console https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/pmc-commands